# How do I fix facebook complaining about my app´s privacy policy?

Tags: facebook

I am getting the following alert 5 times now:

Please update your privacy policy for Attendium to avoid enforcement action. The URL may be missing or returning an error.

I do have a link to the privacy policy, and it is linked both in the canvas app AND our website but I am still getting this error. I can not find any way to contact Facebook to get help resolving this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pfft.  Good luck with that.  They are so completely unresponsive, I'm reasonably sure the entire company is run by robots set to "automatic".

Comment: It's not called Farcebook without good reason...

Comment: Most likely is that your server is not returning 200 OK when we curl the url. If you give me the app id I can look at it